# Fitting HLM models with Heavy-Tailed distribution: robust aproach to lmer?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, robust, fat-tails

I've been using package lmrob in R to estimate models with heavy-tailed distribution of the residuals, which I cannot correct even with transformations of the dependent variable.

I was now planing to step up the models to a HLM framework, but I would like to know if there is a procedure to estimate robust HLM (maybe in lmer package?), even if it is necessary to code something manually.

Any insights are welcome here.

Comment: I think you can explore these packages for your case: hglm or HGLMMM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find HLM variants of the estimators in lmrob in the [robustlmm](https://github.com/kollerma/robustlmm)
 package (this link points to a GitHub rep with instructions on how to install the  package). The syntax is similar to that of lmer.

Comment: This is just perfect! Thanks a lot for pointing me to this package.